# `Rserve` is not recognised as internal or external command.

Tags: java, r, windows, rserve

The basic set-up is to have a Java based UI and R running in the background. **Rserve** utility helps to address this kind of a situation.

It's known that Rserve, although not a package, but can be installed and run like a normal R package. A simple `library(Rserve)` will invoke it and in the Windows Task Manager, you see the process up and running.

However, there is another way around, **without having to go to R console frequently**, by writting a script in Java itself.

```
/**
     * initiate R serve
     */
    try {
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("R CMD Rserve --vanilla"); //I'm stuck here
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is, `R CMD Rserve --vanilla` is not working. It says,

```
`Rserve` is not recognised as internal or external command.
```

My R CMD is perfect, R is working good, so is Rscript but *not* Rserve. I wish to know how do I set the appropriate directory/path for Rserve within the R installation, so that I resolve this error?

Comment: Isn't it only designed for unix environment?

Comment: Well their official release document at https://rforge.net/Rserve/ of 2003 reads :

"2013/08/21 Rserve 1.7-3 released. This relase now restores Windows support (thanks to David Champagne from Revolution Analytics!), it allows HTTPS to WebSockets/TLS upgrade (on unix) and cleans up configuration of the various new possible server configurations."

Comment: From the January 19, 2015 documentation: `"R CMD Rserve will only work on unix when installed from sources and with sufficient permissions to have write-rights in $R_HOME/bin. Binary installations have no way to write in $R_HOME/bin and thus Rserve() function described above is the only reliable way to start Rserve in that case. Java developers may want to see the StartRserve class in java/Rserve/test examples for easy
way to start Rserve from Java."`

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is from way back, but I feel an answer is still warranted for those that are interested.

Following the suggestion:

> Binary installations have no way to write in $R_HOME/bin and thus Rserve() function described above is the only reliable way to start Rserve in that case.

Instead of using

`R CMD Rserve`

use

`Rscript -e "library(Rserve); Rserve()"`

Also, for those that were mystified by the comment in the Rserve documentation (`?Rserve`) about the line:

> Java developers may want to see the StartRserve class in java/Rserve/test examples for easy way to start Rserve from Java.

You can find the class in https://rforge.net/Rserve/snapshot/Rserve_1.8-8.tar.gz by extracting the contents and navigating to *./clients/java/Rserve/test/StartRserve.java*.